# What is the difference between the perfective forms скушать and покушать

Tags: глаголы

I see both forms being mentioned as perfective forms of кушать

Answer (score 6):

*Покушать* (or *поесть*) means to have eaten some unspecified portion of meal, while *скушать* (or *съесть*) is for finishing a whole thing (meal or just dish). A pair of examples:

> Вы хотите есть? -- Нет, спасибо. Я уже покушал. (i.e. I have eaten [something] already.)
>   А где мороженое? -- Я его уже скушал. (I ate it already)
>   Он съел свой обед (He has eaten/finished his lunch)
>   Попейте молока. Покушайте вот хлебца (Take some milk, eat some bread)

Also note that in Russian they more often use the verb form for "having a meal", e.g.: "(по)завтракать / (по)обедать / (по)ужинать" (to breakfast / to dine / to supper) vs. "съесть завтрак / обед / ужин" (to have breakfast / dinner / supper). Although in this context "съесть" doesn't necessarily imply eating meal a whole, yet it is less popular in speech and sounds a little bookish.

Comment: Попейте молока, покушайте вот хлебца. Я заплачу. [Павел Нилин. Интересная жизнь (1969-1980)] [ You can add this point.

Comment: @V.V. Ok, I have rewritten my answer.

Comment: +1 It's an invitation.

Comment: +1. *скушать* is necessarily transitive ("have this"), *покушать* is mostly intransitive ("have some meal").

Comment: @Quassnoi `скушать is necessarily transitive` Except when used in figurative meaning, e.g.: "Ну что, съел?!"